# How to randomly sample from python values in a list?

Tags: python, random, defaultdict

I have a list of stock ticker symbols as values and their sectors as keys in a python `defauldict`.  I would like to randomly sample one or two from each value and place them in their own list, then do some stuff, then randomly sample again and do this for 50 or 100 times.

Is this possible?

Here is the sample of the dictionary.

```
sector_dict = defaultdict(list,
                          {'Technology': ['AAPL', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AMAT', 'FSLR', 'GPRO', 'IBM', 'MSFT', 'MU',
                                          'QCOM', 'TXN', 'XLNX', 'CRM'],
                           'Healthcare': ['ABT', 'GILD', 'MDT', 'BMY'],
                           'Consumer Cyclical': ['AMZN', 'ANF', 'BABA', 'BBY', 'BZUN', 'CMG', 'EBAY', 'GM', 'HD',
                                                 'JD', 'LULU', 'MCD', 'NKE', 'TSLA', 'UA', 'GME'],
                           'Energy': ['APA', 'HAL', 'PBR', 'SLB', 'CVX'],
                           'Industrials': ['BA', 'CAT', 'DE', 'FDX', 'HON', 'UAL'],
                           'Communication Services': ['BIDU', 'FB', 'GOOG', 'NFLX', 'SNAP', 'TWTR', 'ZM', 'CMCSA'],
                           'Real Estate': ['BRX', 'SPG'],
                           'Consumer Defensive': ['COST'],
                           'Basic Materials': ['FCX', 'NEM', 'CLF'],
                           'Financial Services': ['GS', 'HIG', 'LYG', 'MA', 'V', 'C', 'JPM', 'MS']})
```

Replacement can be `True`.  The only constraint is at least one ticker from each key should be chosen.  How do I do this?

When I try, I get a list of lists when all I'm trying to get is a list of values (tickers).

Here was my attempt:

```
import random
random_port = []
for key, val in sector_dict.items():
    random_port.append(random.sample(val, 1))
random_port
```

Comment: The answer to “is it possible” is almost always “Yes” – you’re using a general-purpose language on a computer that is all but a Turing machine.  The question you may intend to ask, “how do I do it”, is too unfocused for Stack Overflow.  Repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Read through the `random` documentation.  Bring us your coding attempt.

Comment: fair enough. I added what I had attempted.

Comment: If that's your only problem, then the solution is simply to `extend` instead of `append`.  Either that, or **flatten** the list after you're done.

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `.append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
random_port = []
for value in sector_dict.values():
    random_port += random.sample(value, min(len(value), 2))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here below I slightly modified your code to select one or two stocks from each category:

```
import random

random_list = []

for key, val in sector_dict.items():
    random_list.extend(random.sample(val, min(len(val), random.randint(1,2))))

print(random_list)
```